# Cannot install dplython for python?

Tags: python, dplyr, installation, pip

For an assignment I am being asked to use the dplython package for python however I cannot seem to install it.

I am using python on visual studio and input my code as shown below

All my online searches are telling me to install it as follows:

```
from gettext import install
import pip

pip install dplython
```

However this does not work and instead get the following error:

```
"dplython" is not defined
```

How should I go about installing this package ?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "However this does not work and instead I get an 'dplython is not defined' error." Please copy **all** the output you are getting from your programs.

Comment: @sarema this is the only output I get when I attempt to run the code

Comment: You are not showing how you start your intepreter, which interpreter you start, etc... And the code is also missing.

Comment: @sarema thanks, I have edited the question slightly. Please let me know if anything else needs to be included in the question

Answer (score 0):

> All my online searches are telling me to install it as follows:

You seem to have mixed up a few things during your online search. The command

```
pip install dplython
```

should not be run from within python, but from your command line

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up a couple of things.

To install a library, execute the following on your command line (bash, cmd, whatever)

```sh
python -m pip install dplython
```

Then you need to import it in your python program.

```py
import dplython
```